registerForActivityResult not able to create File-object from returned Uri

In my app i have written some backup&restore function. Or better i am trying to.
The backup-part works just file but when i try to restore something goes wrong.
i am using a registerForActivityResult to let the user select the restor-file.
So on the onViewCreated method of my fragment is do this:
    mSelectRestoreLauncher = registerForActivityResult( ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult() )
    { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (result.data != null) {
                val fileUri = result?.data?.data
                if (fileUri != null) {
                    val f = File(fileUri.path!!)
                    val sourceStream: InputStream = FileInputStream(f)
                }
            }
        }

the file selector is activated inside a button click with the code:
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    intent.type = "*/*"
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,
                    Uri.parse( Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ))

    mSelectRestoreLauncher.launch(intent)

The selector is shown and the user can select a file.
i even get a filled fileUri back but a soon as my code hits the line where i set "sourceStream" it runs into an exception

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/msf:1000000043: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

anybody an idea what i am doing wrong?

Use a ContentResolver and openInputStream() to get an InputStream on the content identified by the Uri.
